# HTML5 File Drag and Drop no longer works after the first drop

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using HTML5 drag & drop to let the user drag files to my page (from their o/s). This actually works great, and the files get uploaded and everyone is happy.

However, regardless of whether the upload is finished or cancelled, it seems like none of the drag functionality works anymore.

Here's some code (or go to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ControlFreak/gqqVk/)):

HTML:

```
<div id="MainDiv">
    <div id="DropZone" style="display: none;">Drop Files Here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#MainDiv {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#DropZone {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: thick dashed blue;
    border-radius: 12px;
    top: 10%;
    left: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: blue;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('#DropZone').on("dragenter dragend dragleave dragover drop", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $.fn.dndhover = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var self = $(this);
            var collection = $();

            self.on('dragenter', function (event) {
                if (collection.size() === 0) {
                    self.trigger('dndHoverStart');
                }
                collection = collection.add(event.target);
            });

            self.on('dragleave', function (event) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    collection = collection.not(event.target);
                    if (collection.size() === 0) {
                        self.trigger('dndHoverEnd');
                    }
                }, 1);
            });
        });
    };

    $('#MainDiv').dndhover().on({
        'dndHoverStart': function (event) {
            $('#DropZone').show();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        },
            'dndHoverEnd': function (event) {
            $('#DropZone').hide();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#DropZone').bind('drop', function (e) {
        // Show div with dropped files .. user chooses upload or cancel
        $('#DropZone').hide(); // This would eventually happen regardless of success or failure
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you drag a file over the maindiv, the dropzone shows up as expected. If you drop any number of files there, everything works as expected. However, when it's done, if you drag a second file (or group of files) over maindiv, nothing happens anymore.

Any clue where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify ... if you comment out the `$('#DropZone').hide();` the DropZone just stays visible after the drop, which is obviously unacceptable.

Comment: if you use `.css('opacity', '0');` the uploading works again and again. However, I could not get the `ddnHoveStar` to work again. But the `drop` would work is you use opacity. - How it helps slightly.